# Tree Drag and Drop Functionality

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

- label1
  |
  |****label2
  |****label3
   |___label4
   |___label5

I want a tree in this structure, having line between the nodes, also, instead of Open and Close Folders, I have added my own graphic there with label. I did by extending TreeItemRenderer Class. Now, I if iam dragging and dropping a child node ex:label5, and try i drop it above label1 here, it is getting dropped there. i.e.,it is becoming like

label5   ----------> This should not happen.Child should be restricted from being added 
*label1              above parent.
 |
 |**_***label2
 |_*label3
     |___label4

I need to restrict the same. Kindly help me regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom dragging and dropping and apply any logic to this.

See [here](http://flexexamples.blogspot.com/2007/12/flex-drag-and-drop-custom-class-source.html).